# Flip biased coin ind. Find recursion $p_n$ of event of at least $3$ consecutive $H$ in $n$ tosses, in terms of $p_{n−1}, p_{n−2}, p_{n−3}$. Find $p_6$

Tags: probability-theory

I know the recursion formula. It is $p_n = p_{n-1}q + p_{n-2}pq + p_{n-3}p^2q + p^3$, but I am having trouble finding $p_6$.

I was thinking it would be 
$p_3 = p^3$ since it would have to be $H$ on each roll which has a probability of $p$, and 
$p_4 = p_3 + P($1st roll is $T$ and $2, 3, 4$ are $H)$, but that is where I cannot figure out what is next.

Answer (score 1):

To solve this problem in full generality, let $Q_{n,k}$ be the probability that you have flipped $n$ biased coins and never gotten 3 heads in a row, ending with $k$ heads where $k=0,1,2$. Let $P_n$ be the probability that you have already gotten 3 heads in a row after you have flipped $n$ biased coins. Let $p$ be the probability of heads for the coin. Then:

$$Q_{n,k} = pQ_{n-1,k-1}$$

for $k=1,2$, and

$$Q_{n,0} = (1-p)\sum_{k=0}^2 Q_{n-1,k}$$

and

$$P_n = P_{n-1} + p Q_{n-1,2}$$

You can solve this as a multi-variate recurrence for arbitrary $n$, and get something resembling a sum of exponentials formula, or just do the computations by hand since you only need $P_6$. I haven't stated the initial conditions for $P$ and $Q$ for the first 3 coin flips, which you need to get started, but hopefully you can figure that out.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

As you said, $p_3 = p^3$, 
$$p_4 = P(*HHH) + P(HHH*) = 4p^3$$

EDIT:
Note that $*$ in this instance allows for either $H$ or $T$ in that position.
$$P(*HHH) = P(T)P(HHH) + P(HHH)P(T) = (1-p)p^3 + p^3(1-p) = 2p^3(1-p)$$

Comment: does the four come from the fact that you can have the heads in different orders?

Comment: In either term, the $*$ can be replaced by $H$ or $T$, so there are 4 possible scenarios. I'll elaborate an important point.